# « Vous êtes invitées » ou « Vous êtes invités à une soirée » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, conjugaison

J'aimerais bien savoir la quelle de ces deux phrases est juste et pourquoi :

> Vous êtes invitées à une soirée

ou

> Vous êtes invités à une soirée

Et aussi je veux savoir à quel temps la phrase « Vous êtes invités à une soirée » est conjuguée car j'ai cherché la conjugaison du verbe *inviter* et je n'ai pas trouvé ce temps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux sont corrects. Le verbe *inviter* ici est conjugué au présent à la voix passive. La conjuguaison d'un verbe a la voix passive se fait avec l'auxiliaire être suivi du participe passé du verbe ce qui implique que les accords du participe passé doivent être respectés.

Dans le premier cas:

> Vous êtes invitées à une soirée

*Inviter* est au **féminin pluriel** à la voix passive. Ici, « vous » correspond uniquement à des invités de  genre féminin.

Dans le second cas:

> Vous êtes invités à une soirée

*Inviter* est au **masculin pluriel** à la voix passive. Ici « vous » désigne soit uniquement des invités de genre masculin soit des invités de genre féminin avec un ou plusieurs invités de genre masculin. L'utilisation du genre masculin ici se justifie par le fait qu'en français, *l’accord se fait selon le genre masculin même s’il est minoritaire ou implicite.*

Par ailleurs, il faut noter que tous les verbes ne peuvent pas se mettre à la voix passive. Seuls les verbes qui sont transitifs directs peuvent se mettre à la voix passive.

Comment: Il me semble utile de noter que le féminin est à utiliser uniquement si l'ensemble des convives sont des femmes; Dès qu'un de ceux-ci est un homme, le masculin l'emporte => 2 femmes sont invité**e**s , 1000 femmes et 1 homme sont invités

Answer (score 7):

Tout dépend du contexte. Avec l'auxiliaire **être** utilisé ici dans la conjugaison du verbe inviter à la voix passive et au présent de l'indicatif, le participe passé s'accorde **en genre et en nombre** avec le sujet, ici « **vous** ».

> Vous êtes invit**ées** à une soirée

est incorrect si dans le groupe désigné par « **vous** » il y a au moins une personne de sexe **masculin** ou si l'on ne connait pas le sexe des personnes invitées.

> Vous êtes invit**és** à une soirée

est incorrect si « **vous** » ne comprend que des personnes de sexe **féminin**.

Comment: Merci bcp pourriez vous me dire l’intérêt d'utiliser `un verbe à la voix passive`?

Comment: La voix passive met l'accent sur le sujet qui « subit » l'action (ici « vous » = ancien complément d'objet direct de la voix active). Elle permet aussi d'omettre de reprendre le sujet de la voix active comme c'est le cas dans cet exemple où l'on n'indique pas qui invite. La voix active impose un sujet, ex: « Je vous invite à une soirée », « Mes amis vous invitent à une soirée », « On vous invite à une soirée »,etc.

Comment: Merci infiniment pour l'explication